# Indexing Ref field Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, robo3t

I have this field in my model:

```
author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Author' }
```

now my database has more than 20k posts, I want to index this field, I tried to execute this command from studio 3t shell:

```
db.post.createIndex({ author: 1 });
```

but it doesn't work, the query still very slow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB Compass to [create the index](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/indexes/) or verify that the index is present.

You can also use it to [verify that the index is used in your query](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/query-plan/).

Identify whether the issue is that the index isn't created (or not created correctly) or it exists but is not getting used for your query, then address the issue as needed.